# Putting a .png file into a PDF using PyPDF2, but the .png file has jagged edges at its borders

Tags: python, matplotlib, pypdf

This is the graph generated through matplotlib:

[image: pic]

It's saved in a folder, and then it's added to the PDF through the PyPDF2 library.

For reasons unclear, despite the fact the .png is of high quality, on the PDF it appears as having jagged edges (especially near the bottom). These disappear when you zoom in, but they're otherwise always there.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I've added similar .png pictures to powerpoint slides before without having this problem!

Using matplotlib, the image is saved using dpi = 1500:

`fig1.savefig(saving_path, transparent = True,dpi=1500)`

PyPDF2 is used to attach the .png that's outputted into the PDF file:

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

pdf_name = input("Enter the name of the template pdf file to be used (add a .pdf at the end): \n")

output_file = PdfFileWriter()
input_file = PdfFileReader(open(pdf_name, "rb"))

c = canvas.Canvas('image.pdf',pagesize=(2480, 3508)) 
c.drawImage(r'.\matplotlib_pic.png', 440, 600,130,155,mask=[250,255,250,255,250,255]) 

c.save()

image = PdfFileReader(open("image.pdf", "rb"))


input_file = PdfFileReader(open(pdf_name, "rb"))
page_count = input_file.getNumPages()
output_file = PdfFileWriter()

for page_number in range(page_count):
    input_page = input_file.getPage(page_number)
    input_page.mergePage(image.getPage(0))
    output_file.addPage(input_page)

with open("testimageprint.pdf", "wb") as outputStream:

        output_file.write(outputStream)
```

Comment: Can we see an example of the jagged edges?

Comment: Hi fish2000, they are in the original post: https://i.gyazo.com/4798c73adeb0bb1ae42f69ba1c879ed0.png. Parituclarly visible near the bottom. In some PDFs this is much more obvious than the others. The strange thing is when you zoom into the PDFs, they disappear, but if you're viewing the PDF in its intended A4 size, the jagged edges are clear.